# Hiding the values in matrix power bi visual when it is collapsed

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am creating a matrix power bi visual where I have used the +/- expand/collapse feature. If all the rows are collapsed even then its showing the values against the collapsed rows. It doesn't look nice to have values even when its all collapsed. I tried using isinscope function but was not successful as I have multiple fields of date, text which needs to be blank when collapsed.[In the Image you can see that the values are still there if all the Project ID's are collapsed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kxnb.jpg)

I tried using isinscope function but was not successful as I have multiple fields. i could'nt find the option also to change the color of the roll up values.

Comment: What's the next level down from `Project ID` in the matrix? And what's `Activity ID`? In your snip, are you expecting all the columns to be blank apart from `Project ID`?

Comment: There are 4 levels - Project ID->Project Name->Wbs Name->Activity Name. I want the values to be shown (from activity ID to lookahead column) only when I expand to the Activity Name field. If I am not on the last level then it should show blank in the rollups.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to have a measure for each of your Values with something like:

```
Matrix Planned Duration =
  IF(
    ISINSCOPE('YourTable'[Activity Name]),
    SUM('YourTableOrAnotherTable'[PLANNEDDURATION])
  )
```

**NOTE** - one of these measures must show a value for all levels otherwise the matrix won't show anything. So for your `Activity ID` value (since it is a string) - use something like:

```
Matrix Activity ID = 
  IF(
    ISINSCOPE('YourTable'[Activity Name]),
    FIRSTNONBLANK('YourTable[Activity ID], 1),
    "" // note the empty string here
  )
```

The above is just an example and you'll need to adjust accordingly.

As a bonus tip - create a measure like:

```
Matrix Show value = ISINSCOPE('YourTable'[Activity Name])
```

Then use this measure in your `IF` statements above. That way if you need to change it, you only have to do it in the one place.

Comment: Thank you Sam, it worked for me. I did some adjustments and it worked. Thanks again.

Comment: Lovely, please Accept the answer for the benefit of all.